# Explicitly computing the complexification of Lie Algebras.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am currently studying representation theory and the topic of discussion is complexifications of real Lie algebras.

I have noted down that the complexification $\mathfrak{g}^{c}$ of a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is the vector space $\mathfrak{g}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ equppied with the bracket $[X\otimes z,Y \otimes w]^{c}=[X,Y]\otimes zw, X,Y\in\mathfrak{g}, z,w \in \mathbb{C}$.

How would one compute such a complexification explicity? What is let us say the complexification of the algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_{n}\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the set of matrices over $\mathbb{R}$?

An explicit computation would be greatly appreciated and very helpful in me grasping the concept.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think the problem lies with me not being familiar enough with the tensor product. I know how it is defined and constructed but I am not sure where to begin doing explicit computations. We are basically pairing each basis of $gl_{n}(R)$ with the complex number i via the tensor product, how does this result in a vector space isomorphic to $gl_{n}(C)$?

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm not sure I fully understand it yet but there is more than enough literature for me to get there!